# ajax call json no response returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

http://jsfiddle.net/0cp2v9od/

What's wrong here? I can't see my data in console.log, but when I check in the network tab of chrome, it can see my data has successfully returned.

my code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/56alc',
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    timeout: 10000,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: I can see three arrays being printed. Isn't that what you want to be printed?

Comment: If you can't see the data in your console, you've probably filtered the messages in your console. Make sure you've selected to show all messages.

Answer (score 0):

ajax call is working fine. 
Below is the code to display the companies name from success result.

```
$(document).ready(function(){$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/56alc',
cache: false,
async: false,
timeout: 10000,
success: function (data) {
    var companies = "";
    $.each(data, function(index, item){
      companies +=item.CompanyName + "<br/>";

    });
      console.log(companies);
    $("#successDiv").html(companies);
}
```

});
});

http://plnkr.co/edit/RgyU9wDR0Oss0VyrSljt?p=preview